# Same redirect URL for Approve and Reject

Tags: support, authentication

Why, when I'm requesting `/oauth/dialog` and selecting either of the options I get redirected to the same URL with different hash values? It's not a bug per-se, just an observation I made while developing an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how OAuth 2.0 indicates rejection, you get different values on the redirect (either in the hash for the implicit client side flow, or in proper query string parameters for the explicit server side flow).

Instead of `code` or `access_token` (depending on the flow the app is using) you get `error` and `error_description`.  When a user rejects you get `error=access_denied`.

Comment: but shouldn't it return different status code (sorry if it already does) or get redirected to different URL (`login_failure` instead of `login_success`)?

Comment: @Eimantas - nope, not if it's a compliant OAuth 2.0 implementation.  Responses should be 302's (redirects) or 200s (pages displayed as normal to *users* saying an error was encountered).